# mod_fcgid error after upgrading from PHP5.3 to 5.4

Tags: debian, php5, debian-squeeze, mod-fcgid

I just made an upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 via dotdeb.org sources.
After that, I get errors on vhosts with active FastCGI-Application.

```
[Mon May 20 21:05:15 2013] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Mon May 20 21:05:15 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I have a Debian Squeeze root server with Plesk (version 11.0.9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it!**
The problem was the safe_mode option. safe_mode was enabled and caused an error in the header, because safe_mode is not supported in PHP 5.4.